# How to get all rows that are not existing in both tables in R?

Tags: r

I have two tables and I need to find how to get all the rows that are not existing in both tables.

Table A:

```
customer_id
01
02
03
04
05
06
```

Table B

```
customer_id
02
03
06
```

Result expected

```
customer_id
01
04
05
```

Comment: Is Table A a full table? Or are they both not necessarily full tables?

Answer (score 4):

```
library(dplyr)

A <- tibble(customer_id = c("01", "02" ,"03", "04", "05", "06"),
            feature = letters[1:6])
B <- tibble(customer_id = c("02", "03", "06"),
            feature = LETTERS[c(15,16,18)])

anti_join(A, B, by = "customer_id")

# A tibble: 3 × 2
  customer_id feature
  <chr>       <chr>  
1 01          a      
2 04          d      
3 05          e
```

Answer (score 0):

Base `R`

```
A[!A$customer_id %in% B$customer_id,]
```

Output:

```
  customer_id feature
  <chr>       <chr>  
1 01          a      
2 04          d      
3 05          e
```